# Pandas no serpara correctamente el archivo CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estoy intentando tratar un CSV que contiene los datos del coronavirus por provincias, el problema que tengo es que me ha dejado de funcionar, y es porque me ha dejado de leer correctamente el CSV de los datos, tengo lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('2020-03-25.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

Donde las 2 primeras filas son (son todas prácticamente iguales):
Fila 1:

```
Ciudad,Latitude,Longitude,Código país,Diagnosticados,Activos,Recuperados,Muertos,IA,Notas,,,
```

Fila 2:

```
Almería,36.8304075,-2.4637136,Casos detectados,115,105,5,5,"34,57",,,,
```

Las cabeceras (fila 1), me la separa correctamente, el problema está en que me guarda todas las filas dentro de ciudad.

Añado las 2 primeras filas de 1 versión que sí me funcionó:
Fila 1:

```
Ciudad,Latitude,Longitude,Código país,Diagnosticados,Activos,Recuperados,Muertos,IA,Notas,,,
```

Fila 2:

```
Almería,36.8304075,-2.4637136,Casos detectados,91,86,72¹,5,"28,52",¹La Junta no especifica el lugar de las altas y algunas de ellas corresponden a seguimiento domiciliario.,,,
```

No encuentro las diferencias entre ambos, cambiando que tiene más datos, pero al fin y al cabo, con las comas no debería ser un problema.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo no lo puedo reproducir, ¿son los datos de dominio público? Lo digo para comprobarlo con el csv completo a ver si puedo reproducir el problema.

Comment: @FJSevilla No son del todo accesibles así que los he subido a mi drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CqLWU-kWzvcUZP-ioDDyGHV9p1sXiukV/view?usp=sharing

Las filas que no tienen datos (para demarcar comunidades) mi programa se encarga de eliminarlo.

Comment: ¿Generas tu el csv? El problema es que tienes las filas enteramente acotadas menos la primera (headers) y la segunda... Me refiero a las comillas dobles que hay al inicio y final de cada fila, esto le dice a Pandas que es una sola columna y que debe ignorar los delimitadores dentro del string acotado (que es la fila entera...)

Comment: Pues han metido la pata pero bien al generar el csv.. XD de todas formas es simple  de solucionar. Voy a responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es básicamente que han metido la pata al generar el csv, cada linea  (menos las que especifican la comunidad autónoma) está acotada y las celdas que deberían estar acotadas lo están doblemente...

Por ejemplo, la linea:

```
"Granada,37.185112,-3.603804,Casos detectados,579,553,1,25,""34,57"",,,,"
^                                                          ^       ^    ^
^                                                          ^       ^    ^
```

debería ser:

```
Granada,37.185112,-3.603804,Casos detectados,579,553,1,25,"34,57",,,,
```

Como el carácter `"` es el delimitador el parser entiende que toda la fila pertenece a la primera columna ignorando los separadores acotados como debe hacer, dejando el resto de columnas con valor `NaN`.

Es un problema muy específico de este csv, pero podemos resolverlo substituyendo `""` por un nuevo carácter de acotado como `|` y luego eliminado todo carácter `"` solitario que quede:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


out_file = io.StringIO()

with open('2020-03-25.csv') as file:
    out_file.write(file.read().replace('""', '|').replace('"', ""))

out_file.seek(0)

csv = pd.read_csv(out_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar='|')
```

Comment: una vez más: muchísimas gracias